# Forward email from public IP to local host

Tags: linux, port-forwarding

I have a web server running on my public IP address and email server running on my localhost 127.0.0.1 using Mailu.io. I am able to send email from it but when someone replies to the email I want to forward the email from my publicIP:25 to 127.0.0.1:25. How can I do the on linux?

Comment: Does the localhost 127.0.0.1 refer to the same machine where you have your public IP?

If yes, why not configure your email server to listen on public IP as well? Forwarding ports from publicIP:25 to 127.0.0.1:25 would have exactly the same effect, so why unnecessary complication?

Comment: So is that public IP address of yours static?